# CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'. error in MVC 4 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, database-connection, connection-string, dbcontext

After deploying my MVC 4 application, I try to register user, get such error:

**CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.**

Connection string is :

```
<add name="Market" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=endine.arvixe.com; Initial Catalog=Market; Uid=mylogin; Password=mypass; MultipleActiveResultSets=true; " />
```

And DbContext:

```
public class Market: DbContext
    {
        public Market()
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<Market>(new MarketInitializer());
        }
    }


public class MarketInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Market>
    {
        protected override void Seed(Market context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

I accessed to database with SQL Management Studio with same `mylogin` and `mypass`, created `Market` database with script. But in site, can not access database.

How can I find it's reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the issue is this piece of code `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Market>`

```
public class MarketInitializer: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Market>
    {
        protected override void Seed(Market context)
        {
            base.Seed(context);
        }
    }
```

The model has changed at some point,so it is trying to drop the database and recreated it

Comment: Are there any tables in the database the connection string is point at?

Comment: DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges creates a hash of the current model and compares it to the database hash, if they are different then it will drop the database and recreate it.  This is not something that you want when your deploying your application to production

Comment: Now I deleted tables from database. I will try, then will write here the result..

Comment: I deleted this line from code, Database.SetInitializer<Market>(new MarketInitializer());
and deployed again, recreated database again, but still i get that error..

Comment: Are there any other connection strings in the web.config file?

Comment: yes, i have 2 connection string with 1 user. i also remove Initializer from that context. But now, i get "500 - Internal server error" error.

Comment: is the other connection string to do with the SimpleMembershipProvider?

Comment: I use my custom login/register rules. I have my own User table and save login data in cookie with crypting. So, second connection string is like first, only db context name and initial catalog names are different. in local host they works fine..

Comment: What permissions does the SQL Login User `mylogin` have on the server?  does it have elevated permissions with SQL Server like being part of the dbcreator role.  The base issue is that the user `mylogin` does not have create database permission on the SQL Server that is hosting the database.  if you have the option/ability to elevate the `mylogin` user access to allow dtabase creation then that should get you out of your current hole but doesn't fix the reason why your application is trying to create a new database.

Comment: But in hosting i create "mylogin" and select both database for connecting, that is why i can access database with "mylogin" in Management Studio and i can add tables to database..

Comment: are you hosting externally with a third party? I doubt very much that your user will have Create database permission.  try running CREATE DATABASE [test]

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35449/discussion-between-nathan-fisher-and-user1664699)

Comment: I also created database from my host and create their tables by management studio. In this case, I dont need create database. Thanks for your help, Now I get "500 - Internal server error." error, so i think i outrun "CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'." error. 500 - it is a other poblem..

Answer (score 1):

Sometime it happens because you don't have sysadmin role on local SQL Server instance. I found useful article where you can download script command and install it. You will be ask for SQLEXPRESS name or instance name, just you can write 'SQLEXPRESS' and enter. Thats it. It will add you to sysadmin role of local server instance.

Download command from: http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/Project/Download/FileDownload.aspx?ProjectName=addselftosqlsysadmin&DownloadId=9198

Please let me know if it does not work for you.